# Xcode in app purchase showing wrong price

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase

our in app purchase products start to showing wrong price when testing, used to be fine, suddenly the prices come down from productsReqests of the product is wrong, our product is $39.99, but the response come back from apple is $19.99, not sure what happened. Only start to see this today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be that apple have added two new tiers to normal in-app purchases. These are now called

Tier 1,
Tier 1b,
Tier 2,
Tier 2b,
Tier 3,
Tier 4,

Where as the Auto Renewing they have dropped the tier names and just have the prices, so our old tier 4 price has changed to the new equivalent for tier 2b.

In only appears to affect Auto renewing.

You need to go in to the new (and improved) in-app purchase page and update your prices (change prices).

We have decided to wait a couple of days to see if apple change/fix this, as all existing subscriptions will not auto-renew as there is a price change.

Comment: it seems working fine and showing the right prices for the version we have in the store at the moment. and it was showing right prices yesterday, only today, the prices returned is half of what we selected.

Comment: Our live app and the value returned are reduced, today, but were ok yesterday. We have written to apple for support.

Comment: this is very strange, the price in iTuneConnect still showing the right prices

Comment: Agree it is strange. Try selecting the current price to see what it shows, and look at changing it (you can cancel before it goes through).

Comment: tried to make a payment with our live app, the price shows up right.

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in Sandbox, promptly resolved by Apple engineers once I reported it on forums.

Everything seems to work fine for me now. If you still experience problems, linked thread has contact support email.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61851

Answer (score 2):

If your **productIdentifiers** and **priceLocale.identifier** are correct and you just get wrong price (generally less than your price) it is because Sandbox bug. The problem will fix at App Store

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).